# How to pass a function pointer to a function from within that function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I'm attempting to create a simple finite state machine in c++.  The basic idea is that each state in the FSM does some calculations and then returns a function pointer to the next state.  If the state should remain the same then the function returns a pointer to itself.
After failing to create get it to work in c++ as desired I implemented it in python as a sanity check.

```
class FSM:

def __init__(self):
    self.variable =0
    self.currentState = self.state1;            

def state1(self):
    self.variable = self.variable+1;
    print "in state 1, variable =", self.variable
    if self.variable >2:
        return self.state2   
    return self.state1

def state2(self):
    self.variable = self.variable-2
    print "in state2, variable =",self.variable
    return self.state1

def update(self):
    self.currentState = self.currentState()


fsm = FSM();
for i in range(1,10):
   fsm.update()
```

This is what I've written in c++, but it does not compile

```
typedef std::function<void()> fsmFunc;

class FSM
{
  int variable;

  FSM();

  function<fsmFunc()> currentState;

  fsmFunc state1();
  fsmFunc state2();    

  void update();
};

FSM::FSM()
{
  variable =0;
  d.consolePopup<>("sdfsd");
  currentState = bind ( &FSM::state1,this );
}

fsmFunc FSM::state1()
{
  variable++;
  std::cout<<  "In state1, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
  if ( variable >2 )
     return std::bind ( &FSM::state2,this );
  else
     return std::bind ( &FSM::state1,this );
}

fsmFunc FSM::state2()
{
  std::cout<<  "In state2, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
  variable-=2;
  return std::bind ( &FSM::state1,this );
}

void FSM::update()
{
  currentState = currentState();
}
```

I get this error:

```
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'function<void ()>' to 'const function<std::function<void ()> ()>' for 1st argument
```

I have tried lots of different variations but can't get the types to work correctly for the currentState = currentState();

Is this possible in c++?

Comment: Are you using C++11/14, or 03?

Comment: Ahhhh. The Flying Spaghetti Monster embraces C++ in its noodly appendages!

Comment: I am using c++ 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct translation is to construct a recursive type, using what's often called "Fix" or "Mu". I cribbed a bit of my `mu` definition from http://ericniebler.com/2013/07/16/f-algebras-and-c/.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<template<class> class T> struct mu;
template<template<class> class T> struct mu: T<mu<T>> {
    explicit mu(T<mu<T>> t) : T<mu<T>>(t) { }
};

template <class Ret> using no_args_fn = std::function<Ret()>;
typedef mu<no_args_fn> fsmFunc;

class FSM
{

    public:
      FSM();
      void update();

    private:
      fsmFunc currentState;

      fsmFunc state1();
      fsmFunc state2();    

      int variable;
};

FSM::FSM()
  : currentState(std::bind(&FSM::state1, this))
{
  variable = 0;
}

fsmFunc FSM::state1()
{
  variable++;
  std::cout<<  "In state1, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
  if ( variable >2 )
     return fsmFunc(std::bind(&FSM::state2, this));
  else
     return fsmFunc(std::bind (&FSM::state1, this));
}

fsmFunc FSM::state2()
{
  std::cout<<  "In state2, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
  variable-=2;
  return fsmFunc(std::bind(&FSM::state1, this));
}

void FSM::update()
{
  currentState = currentState();
}

int main()
{
    FSM fsm;
    fsm.update();
    fsm.update();
    fsm.update();
    fsm.update();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I don't fully understand exactly how it works yet and was having difficulty creating a default constructor for type fsmFunc.   How would you go about doing that?   For example, if I didn't want to initialise currentState in the constructor of FSM.

Comment: I've also noticed some strange behaviour if I copy the FSM object around. My current solution is to store a pointer to the object because I can't get the move, copy and assignment constructors to work properly with the binding.

Comment: @blooop you can replace the current `explicit` constructor on `mu` with a forwarding constructor `template<class... Args> mu(Args&&... args) : T<mu<T>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }`; this'll let you construct the recursive type from any arguments that could construct the underlying type. In this case though, that's `std::function`, which has a default constructor but not a terribly useful one: you'll get a function that throws `std::bad_function_call` when invoked. I think starting in state 1 is more likely to be the intended behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign next step directly in the method, if would be simpler.
Your current way requires some recursive definition type.

```
class FSM
{
    int variable = 0;
    void (FSM::*currentState) () = &FSM::state1;
public:
    FSM() = default;

    void state1()
    {
      variable++;
      std::cout<<  "In state1, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
      if ( variable >2 )
         currentState = &FSM::state2;
      else
         currentState = &FSM::state1;
    }

    void state2()
    {
        std::cout<<  "In state2, variable: " << variable <<std::endl;
        variable-=2;
        currentState = &FSM::state1;
    }

    void update() { (this->*currentState)(); }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dded801d9e63ecdc).

Comment: Thanks.  I got something similar to this working (your syntax is better though) but I would prefer not to set the state internally because then the compiler will not warn me if I don't return some type of state transition.