# Can you change a pointer to a function from within the currently pointed to function within C?

Tags: c, function, pointers

The short:
I have a function (function_ISR) that points to another function (function_A) and I'd like to know if it is possible, or advisable to change function_ISR such that it points to function_B while in function_A.

The longer:
I am programming a pic micro controller as a stepper controller/driver and am attempting to speed up/simplify the ISR that calculates the interval for the next step and decides what to do next. I currently have it as a state machine, where the states are things like, steady_state, accelerating, decelerating, change_direction. The ISR runs at about 40KHz at peak and spends some it's time falling through the state machine despite it rarely changing state. Furthermore I know the next state at the end of of the last state.

Therefore I'm thinking about writing separate functions for each state and just changing what the ISR points to from within the last state when needed. I'm not sure if it will cause errors when returning from the function and thought I'd ask to see if anybody knows if it would work in principle, if there are any catches for pics or could suggest another way.

Lastly I have checked and found a similar thread/question for C++ [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43503600/how-to-pass-a-function-pointer-to-a-function-from-within-that-function) which I'm not sure if it's correct for C. If you find a better one please reply with the link
Thanks

Comment: Thank you Alex. I didn't want to waste a day to find out what I will try to do was stupid and never going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interrupt vector is just a location in memory that contains the address of the interrupt service routine (ISR). You can change it from within the ISR as long as this change is atomic with respect to the corresponding hardware interruption. You must either disable interrupts or mask the appropriate one or use an instruction that makes the change occur atomically. Depending on your architecture specifics, the ISR may execute with the corresponding interrupt masked until explicitly unmasked. Changing the vector during that time is as straightforward as setting a global variable.

The C++ question in reference is not exactly pertinent, but my answer applies to any compiled language. Assembly OTOH would let you use special instructions explicitly.

Comment: Thank you! The ISR vector in this case points to a a function the determines which interrupt fired (timer, SPI, UART, etc). If it is the step interrupt it then jumps in to the top level function in the question. It is at this point I want it to instead jump to a function that points to the correct state handling.
I'm not sure what you mean by atomic - does that mean at the exact same time?
Interrupts are disabled while in the (or at least my) interrupt routine. I think your answer is essentially yes which is great. Thank you very much for taking the time.

Comment: @Tomas: A change occurs *Atomically* when the complete change cannot be interrupted and allow some other code, such as an interrupt handler or a different thread t see the data in an intermediary state. For example on the antique 8086 processor, changing an interrupt vector required 2 16-bit writes to the 32-bit interrupt vector. Such a change is not atomic. Modern processors have specific instructions for some operations to occur atomically, such as testing and changing a memory location. There instructions are very useful to implement semaphores and mutexes.